# c# read and delete file used for messaging

Tags: c#

I am writing a payments system which communicates with a very old POS interface through files.

The POS system tries to open/create a file (fixed to a single name). If it opens the file it then writes the payment request and closes the file, if it fails to open the file the POS system will wait and try again (sorry don't know how long between attempts, but very short).

I have to monitor the directory and when I see a new file arrive, then I have to try to open the file and block any access to the POS system from writing any new entries.  While I have the file open I read through the records and send them to the payments system, once I receive confirmation I have to close the file and delete it.

My concern/problem is - how do I block the POS system from writing anything between the close and delete statements?

I can set the FileShare to Delete, which allows my program to delete the file before I close it, but this means other processes could also delete the file regardless of whether or not I processed the records successfully.

Option 1

```
void Main()
{
    string filename = @"C:\Temp\CHARGES.TXT";

    using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
    {
        var buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (true)
        {
            var bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            if (bytesRead == 0)
                break;

            var text = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            Console.Write(text);
        }
    }
    File.Delete(filename);
}
```

Option 2

```
void Main()
{
    string filename = @"C:\Temp\CHARGES.TXT";

    using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Delete))
    {
        var buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (true)
        {
            var bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            if (bytesRead == 0)
                break;

            var text = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            Console.Write(text);
        }
        File.Delete(filename);
    }
}
```

As this is a payments system any loss of records is not acceptable.  Also as I have no control over the POS system I cannot change the way it works.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you consider renaming the file before opening it? You can then process the file in your own time, and your POS system can create a new one independently.

Comment: If there is no specific reason you need to block the POS system for a short while, you just want to avoid losing any transactions, do what @peeebeee said, rename/move the file out of the way first and then process it, the POS system will then recreate its own file just afterwards.

Comment: Yes I did, but that means that the account status can get out of sync if the records in the first file fail to process for any reason.

Comment: You didn't mention any such problems, nor did you outline how you *want* to handle that. Please don't make this question a moving target, outline all the limitations, criteria, etc. that you need to consider before having a good solution, only then can people start helping you.

Comment: In order to block the POS system you could open the file for reading and writing, read through it, which blocks the POS system, then truncate the file back to 0 bytes before closing it. If you do this, do you then have to delete it as well?

Comment: Thank you Lasse that would work, as I don't have to actual delete the file - I just have to make sure that I don't process the same records twice.

Comment: Will there be more than one record in the POS file?  Can, for instance, the first record process correctly while record 2 fails, and record 3 succeeds?  Do you process these records as a batch, so if one fails the whole batch rolls back?

Comment: Unfortunately @Sam no it is not batched as each record is sent to a remote api point. So I really will need to process as a queue and remove successful messages out of the queue.  Which leads to: if all are successful then the file is empty; otherwise only unsuccessful records remain and can be added to.

Comment: If I were you, I'd set up a single thread dedicated only to immediately moving any detected incoming files to a new name, and set up your actual processing completely separately from that. Then you should never lose any transactions.

Comment: @Nyerguds while what you state is true with regards to not losing any transactions - it does lead to synchronisation issues though.  If the POS system is getting a balance from the remote system somehow and "knows" to substract any records in this file then if we change the name then the POS will not know about these records.  The POS system is very old and a "black box" so I don't know what it does internally and therefore do not want to possibly comprise it with file renaming.

Comment: Uhh, wait, what? That would imply the POS system _reads_ from the file too? Why would an outbound interface do that?

Comment: No, what I am saying is - I don't know what is does.  However I do know that it uses credit limits to say whether or not you can have more "somethings" (technical term), which "could" use the incomplete records as part of the calculation.  So I am saying it is better not to change things as I don't know what effect they will have on the rest of the system.

Comment: Just as an added note - I won't have access to the POS system while developing, and probably not during testing either until UAT, so I cannot test what will happen if I rename a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @Lasse and @Sam for your helpful comments.  I have made the following changes to the code:

```
void Main()
{
    string filename = @"C:\Temp\CHARGES.TXT";
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;

    using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read))
    {
        // get a big enough buffer to hold the whole file and read it in
        long fileSize = new FileInfo(filename).Length;
        var buffer = new byte[fileSize];
        var bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        try
        {
            // convert each line to ASCII to process through to API
            while (end < bytesRead)
            {
                while (end < bytesRead && buffer[end] != 0x0A && buffer[end] != 0x0D)
                {
                    end++;
                }
                var text = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, start, end - start);

                // Send to API
                Console.WriteLine("Start [{0}] End [{1}] Text [{2}]", start, end, text);

                if (end < bytesRead)
                {
                    end += 2;
                    start = end;
                }
                if (end > bytesRead / 2)
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("just to prove the partial");
        }       
        finally
        {
            // convert any remaining records back to bytes and write back to file
            fs.SetLength(0);
            fs.Write(buffer, end, bytesRead - end);
        }
    }
}
```

The process will now go through the file and write back any failed/unprocessed messages to the file at the end - this covers off my locking concerns as well as covering the individual record failures.

Thank you agin

Comment: Why are you not using `StreamReader` to get the text processing handled for you? Just one snag, disposing StreamReader will dispose the underlying Stream, so you need to truncate the file before you do that.

Comment: @Lasse thank you for your comment, but I am not sure what that gains me other than the byte to ASCII conversion.  I would still have to read the whole file and then break into lines for processing through the API.  Any failed or unprocessed records would need to be written back to the file before closing (@Sams point about each record being processed completely autonomously) and releasing the lock and the StreamReader does not support writing so that would mean introducing a StreamWriter(?) as well.  Happy for you to advise me further as I have not used those.